# how to pass parameter to singleton in java

Tags: java, singleton

I need to display name from database using type ahead feature in my web application. I used Dojo filtering select to display names . those names have to be displayed in multiple jsp page. I have a Java class named getClientNames() that gets the list of names from the database . based on a condition list of names will vary. So i will pass a parameter to that java class ,based on the parameter it executes the query.

eg,

```
 public class X{
public List<String> getNames(String param){
    if param.equals("x"){
    //query 1
    }
    else{
    //query 2
    }
    return clisntList;
}
```

i have a Singleton class to call getNames method.

```
 public class ClassicSingleton {
private static ClassicSingleton instance = null;
List<String> clientList;
protected ClassicSingleton() {
    // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
}
public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new ClassicSingleton();
    }
    return instance;
}

public List<String> getName(){
    X obj=new obj();
    this.clientList=obj.getNames(param);
    return this.clientList;
}
 }
```

i need to pass a parameter to this singleton method getName to get proper result. How can i achieve it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why in the world would you have `clientList` as a member field? You only access it inside `getName` where you always set it right before you use it - other than blocking the optimizer and introducing a race condition it doesn't really do anything!

Once you move `clientList` inside the function, it makes more sense to add an argument to `getName` and pass it to `getNames`:

```
public List<String> getName(String param){
    X obj=new obj();
    List<String> clientList=obj.getNames(param);
    return clientList;
}
```

Also, there is no reason to use the singleton patten here, since you don't really use the state of `ClassicSingleton`. You can simply make `getName` a static method:

```
public static List<String> getName(String param){
    X obj=new obj();
    List<String> clientList=obj.getNames(param);
    return clientList;
}
```

Comment: i am using this throughout the web application.which is the best design? singleton or simple class?

Comment: Neither. Unless there is a specific reason why you need an object, a static method will do. Depending on `obj.getNames`' implementation, you should probably be able to make it static as well(after all - you don't really set the state of the `obj` you create in `ClassicSingleton.getName`...)  and ditch `ClassicSingleton` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<String> getName(String param){
    X obj=new X();
    return obj.getNames(param);
}
```

and then:

```
 ClassicSingleton.getInstance().getName(param)
```

works for you?